# how to use countif function having the criteria as a part of string literal?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

For example i want to count the number of "johns" appearing in the column A however column has both first name and last name and i want to count all the johns irrespective of their last name.

I am using the below code however doesn't seem to work:

```
Range("A199").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)), Cells.Find(What:="John "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @YowE3K commented, there is a reason why I use `"=" & "John*")`. It's a preparation for using a variable in the future instead of the hard-coded "John".

If you want to use a VBA solution , you can use:

```
Range("A199").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)), "=" & "John*")
```

Or, better yet:

```
Const NametoFind As String = "John"

Range("A199").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)), "=" & NametoFind & "*")
```

**Note**: `Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))` will work for continous range only (not if you have blank cells in the middle of you range).

Comment: `"=" & "John*"`?  Really??  That wastes 5 keystrokes!  Whatever happened to just using `"=John*"`??!?!  (Just joking - there's a good reason to do what you did, or even better `"=" & "John" & "*"` - it makes it easier to replace the hard-coded `"John"` with a variable instead.)

Comment: @YowE3K you are right, I was half-way in the answer, when I had to attend a work meeting (don't you just hate it when work interferes with your **SO**)

Comment: I can't really complain when I have a work meeting - I figure I need to give the company at least 30 minutes of my time each work day.  ;)

Comment: Also can you suggest if I want to do an IF condition where the condition is to again match with a particular subtext of a text then how can i do it . i was trying with this one  If ActiveCell.Value = "Benchmark report " & "*"...doesnt seem to work

Comment: @prernaarora sound like a great new **SO** post

Answer (score 3):

You don't need VBA. You can use a wildcard with COUNTIF/COUNTIFS - make your criteria "John*" (so, `=COUNTIF(A1:A7, "John*")`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use an extra column, make one right after you name column, using the following formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("JOHN"; A1)
```

The above example should be in cell `B1`. Then you will get a `TRUE` if the cell in column A contains the name "JOHN", otherwise you will get a `FALSE`. Then you simply make a count:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B; TRUE)
```

It might be a slight disadvantage that you have to use an extra column. But on the plus-side, it is very understandable (both for yourself and others whom might read your code).